# .Net Core MVC Form submission posts to database, but View throws error

Tags: mysql, model-view-controller, visual-studio-code, asp.net-core-3.0

As the title implies, posting the data to the database isn't the problem. The problem is what happens to the web page itself once the data is posted. Basically, I want the user to stay on the page after submitting the form. After adding details about a company, the user clicks submit, gets a message saying 'add successful', the form clears, and then it's ready for another submission.

Instead, the data gets sent, but then I get an error:

InvalidOperationException: The view 'AddCompany' was not found. The following locations were searched:
/Views/AddCompany/AddCompany.cshtml
/Views/Shared/AddCompany.cshtml

To save space, I won't show all the code for each section, but hopefully you get the idea.

Model code:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<CommunicationDetails>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(e => e.FirstContactDate)
                    .HasName("PRIMARY");

                entity.Property(e => e.FirstContactDate).HasColumnType("date");

                entity.Property(e => e.CompanyName)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasColumnType("varchar(50)")
                    .HasCharSet("latin1")
                    .HasCollation("latin1_swedish_ci");

                entity.Property(e => e.FirstContactMethod)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasColumnType("varchar(20)")
                    .HasCharSet("latin1")
                    .HasCollation("latin1_swedish_ci");
```

... and so on.

Controller code:

```
namespace dotnetproject2.Controllers
{
    public class AddCompanyController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult AddCompany()
        {
            return View();
        }

    [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult AddCompany (CompanyDetails company) {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                using (AddCompanyContext db = new AddCompanyContext())
                {
                    db.CompanyDetails.Add(company);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
                ModelState.Clear();
                ViewBag.Message = company.companyName + " has been added.";
            }
            return View();
        }
    }
```

View code:

```
<form id="company-form" asp-controller="AddCompany" asp-action="AddCompany" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-4" for="companyName">Company Name</label>
                <input type="text" asp-for="companyName" id="companyName" class="form-control-sm col-sm-6">
            </div>      
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-4" for="publicEmail">Public Email</label>
                <input type="text" asp-for="publicEmail" id="publicEmail" class="form-control-sm col-sm-6">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-4" for="contactPersonOne">Contact Person 1</label>
                <input type="text" asp-for="contactPersonOne" id="contactPersonOne" class="form-control-sm col-sm-6">
            </div>
```

Sorry if this post is way too long. Wasn't sure how much code to include. Please ignore the weird indentations as well; everything is normal in my IDE.

Also, I'm using VS Code, so there's a good chance a Visual Studio-based solution to this issue won't work for me. For example, using the controller to scaffold the view doesn't appear to be an option for me.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure if this should technically be a comment, but I solved the problem.

I still don't know where I went wrong with the code above, but the bigger problem was my approach. What I should have done from the beginning was just follow the tutorial on Microsoft's documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

I had no idea scaffolding CRUD code for models/views/controllers can be done with a few simple commands. I thought scaffolding like that was only available for Visual Studio, because when I right-clicked on things like they do on YouTube tutorials, the scaffold option wasn't there for me using VS Code. Now I know I can do the same thing, just through the CLI.

So the overall takeaway: DO NOT haphazardly go searching for tutorials for every little thing you want to do. Just follow the tutorials on Microsoft's Documentation that take care of big chunks of your project (like CRUD). Just remember to know your .Net Core version when you're installing the packages they tell you to install in the tutorials.